# Using a HT12D pulse to drive a latching relay

Tags: voltage, current, rf, relay

I am receiving a signal via RF and using a HT12D to decode it and send a 5V DC pulse.  I want to use this pulse to drive a latching relay.  On the first pulse it will make the relay latch in NO position and the next time there is a pulse I want the relay to return to the NC position.  I want the relay to retain its position even if the power is interrupted and if possible have a push button to change between states also.  The relay needs to handle either 24V AC at 500mA or 12V DC at 500mA.

I have read about a 74hc73 to clock the signals but I became somewhat confused where to attach the signal input and it seemed to have more than one relay. 
Can someone help me out with a previous post and online link or some personal experience?

I am including a schematic that supposedly will allow a high signal to latch and unlatch a relay.  I'm not sure what type of relay to use and where to input the 5v pulse for my HT12D at.

Could someone look at the schematic and tell me:
1. Will it work to latch and unlatch relay with input of 5v pulse from HT12D?
2. If so where should I connect the HT12D?
3. What type of relay should I use?
4. Will this reset if power is lost? I don't want that so how can I keep it from doing so.
[image: This is the schematic using 74hc73 to switch relay every time a pulse is entered]

Comment: Please ask a direct question that is appropriate for this site.

Comment: So I bought the components and set this up on a breadboard and when I push the button it triggers the relay (non latching) but when I let go the switch the relay returns to normal state just like I would do by pulling high.  To apply to a latching relay as soon as I attach the power to set up the relay triggers then I have to change the leads to the relay and it resets when I do that.  QUESTION: Is this the right set up to use with a latching relay where I want to use push button and 5vdc pulse to switch the relay on and off.  If not what can I do and if yes what am I doing wrong.